# How can I add content to the page by just using css/js?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I'm developing a real estate website. The website is working with a paid service that allows people to view real estate listings through my website. My website becomes a subdomain of the other website like www.mywebsite.listingswebsite.com. The listings website dynamically pulls the header and footer wrappers on one of the pages I provided them, and puts their content in the middle of the page. So it looks like this.

```
My Header
Their listings content that I have no control over
My Footer
```

The problem is, I want to modify their page. I want to add some content before their content, I want to move elements around, and I want to delete some elements. For now, all I know is how to remove elements from the page - and that's by finding the ID of their Div, and adding display:none in my CSS file.

But what if I wanted to add content to the page? I only have control over the CSS/JS, so how would I do that? Say I wanted to add a picture right before their content.

Comment: are you using an iframe to display their content?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery can be your best friend man, http://jquery.com, Just target your desired id and:

```
// Waits until the dom is ready
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mytarget").html("this replaces all content in the target");
  $("#mytarget").append("this places your content after content in the target");
  $("#mytarget").prepend("this places your content before content in the target");
});

// Waits until everything is loaded
$(window).load(function(){
  $("#mytarget").html("this replaces all content in the target");
  $("#mytarget").append("this places your content after content in the target");
  $("#mytarget").prepend("this places your content before content in the target");
});
```

Comment: Can I just write jQuery the same way I would write regular javascript? Just put it in a js file and link to it?

Comment: I downloaded the file, figured it out

Comment: I tried prepend. It works when I test it out on my own pages. But when I type in a div ID on a page that isn't mine (sub domain page) it doesn't work. My guess is that it pulls the header and footer wrappers first and then loads up their divs, so it doesn't connect. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, answer the comment in the question. @Mike

Comment: hey mike, have you tried wrapping the calls in a document or window ready? I've edited my answer to show you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this Documentation off jQuery about [DOM Insertion](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/) , and this about [Css](http://api.jquery.com/category/css/),they contain all what you need to manipulate DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Jquery, you can add some content with [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/), [preprend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/), "after" or "before" methods. Hope this will help you.

(I'm sorry, i can only post 2 links, but you can find them easily if you want some examples ;))